# vim : how to write to another file my lines yanked?

Tags: vim

I can do it with marks for exemple

```
:'a,'b w! /tmp/myFile
```

But what is the syntaxt with yanked lines ?

Thanks

Comment: How did you yank them? If by using a range, why not write them immediately to the file?

Comment: 1/ I've yanked 100 lines for example (so if I would type 'p' in escape-mode, they would be added in my current file)
2/ I just want to type a command (by ':' to the bottom) to create a file containing these lines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Hard Way

You can call vim functions in command mode.
The command below will write yanked lines to `/tmp/myFile`.

```
:call writefile(split(getreg('"'), '\n'), '/tmp/myFile')
```

**Note:** Yanked lines are in unnamed register (`""`, type `:help registers` for help).

---

### Easy Way

Why not do it visually. Just 3 basic commands everyone can understand:

- `:tabe` -- open new tab
- `p` -- paste to buffer
- `:w /tmp/myFile.txt` -- save file

Answer (score 5):

You could use `:redir` (using register `r`):

```
:redir! > /tmp/myFile | silent echon @r | redir END
```

If you wanted to append you could use `redir >> /tmp/myFile` (note: no `!` here, as "overwrite if exists" wouldn't make sense).

Answer (score 2):

The other answers use special commands like `:redir` or `writefile()` to write to a new file. The most direct way is through opening a buffer for the file. This way, you can use the ordinary `p` / `:put`. As a bonus, the file stays in the buffer list, so it's easy to recall / edit later.

```
:split /tmp/myFile | put! | write | bdelete
```

or shortened:

```
:sp /tmp/myFile|pu!|w|bd
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers directly answer the question, but there is *another way* that is **probably shorter** that **does not involve yanking**. Instead of writing yanked text to a file, you can write **visually selected** text to a file. Use `v` commands and then, while in visual mode press `:`. At the bottom of your screen you will see:

```
:'<,'>
```

Then just use `write filename.extension` or `w filename.extension` for short. For example:

```
:'<,'>write new_file.txt
```

or

```
:'<,'>w new_file.txt
```

This is very fast and easy for me.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative way of solving the problem. I see tha answer is not directly about lines already yanked, so I hesitate to upvote. I hope other reviewers will appreciate the answer.